# How to shuffle a list?

Tags: haskell

How can I sample without replacement from a set of numbers (`[1, 2, 3]`) until I hit `x`?
 My plan was to shuffle the list `[1, 2, 3]` and chop it at `x`:

```
-- chopAt 3 [2, 3, 1] == [2, 3]
-- chopAt 3 [2, 1, 3] == [2, 1, 3]
-- chopAt 3 [3, 1, 2] == [3]
chopAt _ [] = []
chopAt x (y:ys)
  | x /= y    = y : chopAt x ys
  | otherwise = [y]
```

However I could not figure out how to shuffle the list (or understand Monads yet).

```
-- sample without replacement from [1, 2, 3] until one hits a 3
-- x <- shuffle [1, 2, 3]
-- print (chopAt 3 x)
main = do
-- shuffle [1, 2, 3]
  print (chopAt 3 [1, 3, 2])
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use [random](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/1.0.0.3/doc/html/System-Random.html) and maybe even [MonadRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.3/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random.html) to implement your shuffles. A few good answers exist [here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Random_shuffle)

But that's really operational. Here's what's going on behind the scenes.

### I.

Randomness is one of the first places in Haskell that you encounter and have to handle impurity---which seems offensive, because shuffles and samples seem so simple and don't feel like they ought to be bundled up with printing to a physical screen or launching nukes, but often `purity == referentially transparent` and referentially transparent randomness [would be useless](https://xkcd.com/221/).

```
random = 9 -- a referentially transparent random number
```

So we need a different idea about randomness to make it pure.

### II.

A typical "cheat" in scientific code used to enhance reproducibility—super important—is to fix your random seed of an experiment so that others can verify that they get *exactly the same results* every time your code is run. This is exactly referential transparency! Let's try it.

```
type Seed = Int
random :: Seed -> (Int, Seed)
random s = (mersenneTwisterPerturb s, splitSeed s)
```

where `mersenneTwisterPerturb` is a pseudorandom mapping from `Seed`s to `Int` and `splitSeed` is a pseudorandom mapping from `Seed`s to `Seed`s. Note that both of these functions are totally deterministic (and referentially transparent), so `random` is as well, but we can create an infinite, lazy pseudorandom stream like so

```
randomStream :: Seed -> [Int]
randomStram s = mersenneTwisterPerturb s : randomStream (splitSeed s)
```

Again, this stream is deterministic based on the `Seed` value, but an observer who sees only the stream and not the seed should be unable to predict its future values.

### III.

Can we shuffle a list using a random stream of integers? Sure we can, by using modular arithmetic.

```
shuffle' :: [Int] -> [a] -> [a]
shuffle' (i:is) xs = let (firsts, rest) = splitAt (i `mod` length xs) xs
                     in (head rest) : shuffle' is (firsts ++ tail rest)
```

Or, to make it more self-contained, we can precompose our stream generating function to get

```
shuffle :: Seed -> [a] -> [a]
shuffle s xs = shuffle' (randomStream s) xs
```

another "seed consuming" referentially transparent "random" function.

### IV.

So this seems to be a repeating trend. In fact, if you browse the module `System.Random` you'll see lots of functions like what we wrote above (I've specialized some type classes)

```
random :: (Random a) => StdGen -> (a, StdGen)
randoms :: (Random a) => StdGen -> [a]
```

where `Random` is the type class of things which can be generated randomly and `StdGen` is a kind of `Seed`. This is already enough actual working code to write the necessary shuffling function.

```
shuffle :: StdGen -> [a] -> [a]
shuffle g xs = shuffle' (randoms g) xs
```

and there's an `IO` function `newStdGen :: IO StdGen` which will let us build a random seed.

```
main = do gen <- newStdGen
          return (shuffle gen [1,2,3,4,5])
```

But you'll notice something annoying: we need to keep varying the gen if we want to make *different* random permutations

```
main = do gen1 <- newStdGen
          shuffle gen1 [1,2,3,4,5]
          gen2 <- newStdGen
          shuffle gen2 [1,2,3,4,5]

          -- using `split :: StdGen -> (StdGen, StdGen)`
          gen3 <- newStdGen
          let (_, gen4) = split gen3
          shuffle gen3 [1,2,3,4,5]
          let (_, gen5) = split gen4
          shuffle gen4 [1,2,3,4,5]
```

This means you'll either have to do lots of `StdGen` bookkeeping or stay in IO if you want different random numbers. This "makes sense" because of referential transparency again---a set of random numbers have to be random *with respect to each other* so you need to pass information from each random event on to the next.

It's really annoying, though. Can we do better?

### V.

Well, generally what we need is a way to have a function take in a random seed then output some "randomized" result and the *next* seed.

```
withSeed :: (Seed -> a) -> Seed -> (a, Seed)
withSeed f s = (f s, splitSeed s)
```

The result type `withSeed f :: Seed -> (a, Seed)` is a fairly general result. Let's give it a name

```
newtype Random a = Random (Seed -> (a, Seed))
```

And we know that we can create meaningful `Seed`s in `IO`, so there's an obvious function to convert `Random` types to `IO`

```
runRandom :: Random a -> IO a
runRandom (Random f) = do seed <- newSeed
                          let (result, _) = f seed
                          return result
```

And now it feels like we've got something useful---a notion of a random value of type `a`, `Random a` is just a function on `Seed`s which returns the next `Seed` so that later `Random` values won't all be identical. We can even make some machinery to compose random values and do this `Seed`-passing automatically

```
sequenceRandom :: Random a -> Random b -> Random b
sequenceRandom (Random fa) (Random fb) = 
    Random $ \seed -> let (_aValue, newSeed) = fa seed in fb newSeed
```

but that's a little silly since we're just throwing away `_aValue`. Let's compose them such that the second random number actually depends materially on the first random value.

```
bindRandom :: Random a -> (a -> Random b) -> Random b
bindRandom (Random fa) getRb = 
    Random $ \seed -> let (aValue, newSeed) = fa seed
                          (Random fb)       = getRb aValue
                      in fb newSeed
```

We also ought to note that we can do "pure" things to `Random` values, for instance, multiplying a random number by 2:

```
randomTimesTwo :: Random Int -> Random Int
randomTimesTwo (Random f) = Random $ \seed -> let (value, newSeed) = f seed
                                              in (value*2, newSeed)
```

which we can abstract out as a Functor instance

```
instance Functor Random where
  fmap f (Random step) = Random $ \seed -> let (value, newSeed) = step seed
                                           in (f value, newSeed)
```

and now we can create cool random effects like Brownian motion

```
brownianMotion :: Random [Int]
brownianMotion = 
   bindRandom random $ \x -> 
       fmap (\rest -> x : map (+x) rest) brownianMotion
```

### VI.

And this gets to the heart of the whole matter that I've been writing up to. Randomness can exist in the `IO` monad perfectly well, but it can also exist on its own as a simpler `Random` monad. We can write the instance immediately.

```
instance Monad Random where
  return x = Random (\seed -> (x, seed))
  rx >>= f = bindRandom rx f
```

And since it's a monad, we get free `do` notation

```
brownianMotion' = do x <- random
                     rest <- brownianMotion'
                     return $ x : map (+x) rest
```

and you could even get fancy and call `runRandom` a monad homomorphism, but that's a very different topic.

So, to recap

1. randomness in a referentially transparent language needs `Seed`s
2. carting `Seed`s are is annoying
3. there's a common pattern to "lifting" and "binding" random values which routes the `Seed`s around naturally
4. that pattern forms a monad

And the really short answer is that you probably want to be using [random](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random/1.0.0.3/doc/html/System-Random.html) and maybe even [MonadRandom](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/MonadRandom/0.1.3/doc/html/Control-Monad-Random.html) to implement your shuffles. They'll come in handy for "sampling" generally.

Cheers!

Comment: See also [random-fu's shuffle function](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random-fu/0.2.4.0/doc/html/Data-Random-List.html#v:shuffle).

Comment: random-fu just kicks the shuffling down to [random-shuffle](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/random-shuffle/0.0.3/doc/html/System-Random-Shuffle.html)'s `shuffle :: [a] -> [Int] -> [a]` which is, to be honest, a *muuuch* better shuffling algorithm than I have above. There's also `shuffle' :: RandomGen gen => [a] -> Int -> gen -> [a]` which ties into the `System.Random` random functionality directly.

Comment: So what do you do if you *don't* want seeds, because you want a hardware RNG instead?

Comment: Ultimately you probably do want seeds (it's ultra slow otherwise) so you just need to ensure that you get them from a good entropy source and put them into a good PRNG. If you genuinely want hardware only randomness then there's an easy function to write of type `IO Bit`.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson, what I mean is that it seems tricky to take code that assumes seed splitting and convert it to use an entropy pool. Or is there some monadic magic I'm missing? (Please ping me so I see your response.)

Comment: @dfeuer My understanding is that you nearly always want to pull your initial seed from an entropy pool and then use a PRNG from there, so I think I'm not familiar with what you're looking for. If you want to draw from an entropy pool each time then `newtype M a = M (IO a)` seems best, right?

Comment: @J.Abrahamson, I guess you could do that, yeah.

Comment: Using your `shuffle` from **III.** with (finite, or) an infinite "stream" of `is` (ie `cycle [837687365, 83748347, 2390293,
        817218, 8127283, 2893827,
        83748475, 94859485, 9343984,
        458745878, 94854959,
        873473, 90264981365450]`) errors out with **`Prelude.last: empty list`** for simple test `xs`s such as `[3..8]` etc. Even when prepending `shuffle [] xs = xs` and `shuffle _ [] = []` .. ideas?

Comment: `shuffle' [8..] [1,2]` is enough to throw. This is because `(firsts, rest) = splitAt (8 \`mod\` length [1..2])` splits at 0 therefore `firsts = []` and `last firsts` throws.

Comment: One either has to add 1 to the split index or switch from `last first` to `head rest`. I have updated the answer with the second option. Please review.

Answer (score 5):

For shuffling a list, use the [random-shuffle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-shuffle-0.0.4) library:

```
import System.Random (newStdGen)
import System.Random.Shuffle (shuffle')

main = do
  rng <- newStdGen

  let xs = [1,2,3,4,5]

  print $ shuffle' xs (length xs) rng
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for [permutations](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3apermutations)?

Also it seems that `cropAt` can be implemented via `takeWhile`. I personally prefer standard combinators over hand-made.

Answer (score 2):

Bellow you may find some simple solution from beginning of my Haskell learning. If truth to be told, I'm still at the beginning or just slightly behind ;-)

```
import System.Random
import Control.Applicative

shuffle :: [a] -> IO [a]
shuffle [] = return []
shuffle lst = do
    (e, rest) <- pickElem <$> getIx
    (e:) <$> shuffle rest
    where
    getIx = getStdRandom $ randomR (1, length lst)
    pickElem n = case splitAt n lst of
        ([], s) -> error $ "failed at index " ++ show n -- should never match
        (r, s)  -> (last r, init r ++ s)
```

Answer (score 2):

Everyone seem to have encountered this at one point in time or another. This is my quick solution to a problem:

```
import System.Random

shuffle :: [a] -> IO [a]
shuffle [] = return []
shuffle xs = do randomPosition <- getStdRandom (randomR (0, length xs - 1))
                let (left, (a:right)) = splitAt randomPosition xs
                fmap (a:) (shuffle (left ++ right))
```

Note that the complexity is O(N^2), so this is pretty inefficient for larger lists. Other way is to implement [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) by using mutable arrays (linear complexity):

```
import Data.Array.IO
import System.Random

swapElements_ :: (MArray a e m, Ix i) => a i e -> i -> i -> m ()
swapElements_ arr i j = do a <- readArray arr i
                           b <- readArray arr j
                           writeArray arr i b
                           writeArray arr j a
                           return ()

shuffle :: [a] -> IO [a]
shuffle xs = do let upperBound = length xs
                arr <- (newListArray (1, upperBound) :: [a] -> IO (IOArray Int a)) xs
                mapM_ (shuffleCycle arr) [2..upperBound]
                getElems arr
  where shuffleCycle arr i = do j <- getStdRandom (randomR (1, i))
                                swapElements_ arr i j
```

Answer (score 1):

add this function to your code then call it like this `shuffle (mkStdGen 5) [1,2,3,4,5]`

```
import System.Random

shuffle gen [] = [] 
shuffle gen list = randomElem : shuffle newGen newList
  where 
   randomTuple = randomR (0,(length list) - 1) gen
   randomIndex = fst randomTuple
   newGen      = snd randomTuple
   randomElem  = list !! randomIndex
   newList     = take randomIndex list ++ drop (randomIndex+1) list
```

Or include it in your `do` block like that

```
main = do
     r <- randomIO
     str <- getLine 
     putStrLn (show (shuffle (mkStdGen r) str))
```

Comment: That's very inefficient for long lists.